# How can I change the direction of edges in python igraph?

Tags: python, graph, igraph, data-manipulation

I have a directed tree graph with a single root vertice, where the directions seem arbitrary.
I want all edges to be directed from the single root, towards the ends of the respective branches.

My first primitive attempt was to swap the source and target vertices like below (but as assumed, it would not work.

```
temp = g.es[e_idx].source
g.es[e_idx].source = g.es[e_idx].target
g.es[e_idx].target = temp
```

Is there a function or a set of functions that allow to swap the direction of a specific edge available?

Or a way to manipulate the source / target attributes of edges, without needing to change any vertice attributes?

Please let me know if I need to specify anything further.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you will need to re-build the graph from scratch. The endpoints of an edge are not "attributes" that can be manipulated. Do you have any edge or vertex attributes (such as edge weights) that need to be retained? BTW a few months ago I've opened a feature request for a function that will make this easy, see https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/1770

Comment: Note: it's *igraph*, not *i-graph*.

Comment: This would be a great feature!  

"The endpoints of an edge are not "attributes" that can be manipulated", I was afraid that was the case. :-/ (not familiar with igraph, yet)
As far as I understand, the difference in directed and undirected graphs is that edges are stored in the graph as a multiset, I therefore assume that the directed g uses a "frozenset". 
So edges in directed graphs have some thing like "_source_vertex" and "_target_vertex" in python.

Indeed, I have attributes on edges and vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that preserves all graph attributes:

- We are going to reorder vertices so that those closer to the root come first
- Then we use `to_directed` with the `"acyclic"` mode, which directs edges from lower to higher index vertices
- Finally we restore the original vertex order

```
import igraph as ig
from igraph import Graph

# Set seed for reproducibility
import random
random.seed(123)

# Create an undirected tree. If your tree is not undirected, 
# convert it to undirected first.
g = Graph.Tree_Game(10)

# Our chosen root:
root = 3

ig.plot(g, vertex_label=range(g.vcount()), layout = g.layout_reingold_tilford(root=root), bbox=(300,300))

# Distances from the root, will be used for ordering:
dist=g.shortest_paths(source=root)[0]

# This function computes the permutation that would
# sort 'elems'. It also serves as a way to invert
# permutations.

def ordering(elems):
    return sorted(range(len(elems)), key=elems.__getitem__)

# Compute orderings based on the distance from the root:
perm = ordering(dist)
invperm = ordering(perm)

# Reorder, direct, restore order:
dg = g.permute_vertices(invperm)
dg.to_directed('acyclic')
dg = dg.permute_vertices(perm)

# Plot again.
# Now the root does not need to be given,
# as it is auto-detected from the directions.
ig.plot(dg, vertex_label=range(g.vcount()), layout='reingold_tilford', bbox=(300,300))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution!

After an update I could run the example as well as the adoption to my case.

Worked like a charme for the graph with around 3000 edges and vertices.
At least I confirmed the persistence of the attributes and the uniform direction of edges from root using: `dg.is_tree(mode='out')`